# MySQL DB creation with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to create a DB in MySQL and then in the same script execution go and add values to one of the tables in the DB?

Comment: Simple answer: "yes, it is possible". What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: what answer do you wait? but, yes this is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can. For example:

```
//Create the database
$pdo->query('CREATE DATABASE dbname');

//Select the database
$pdo->query('USE dbname');

//Create your table
$pdo->query('CREATE TABLE example...etc');

//Insert data into your table.
$pdo->query('INSERT INTO example...etc');
```